# Export and Import TileMill/ Mapbox

Tags: mapbox, tilemill

Do you know any way to export a project from TileMill and Import that project in other computer with TileMill?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Well, I don't know if this is the right way, but apparently it's working.

To export the project settings go to the MapBox folder (in your user documents folder) and copy the project folder that you want to export.

Copy this folder in the same place in the final computer.

I had problems with the layers, so if you have errors when you run the project, don't worry. This is because some layers was linked from a file, so you should copy this file and modify the path of the file in the layer, if the layer is linked with an url, that'll work perfectly.

I could check that path, is an absolute path, I didn't try with a relative path, which would be very useful.

I hope this help someone.

Thanks